# Inheriting from a child class of Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I have a type of **Window** which I am using quite often (with an OK button and code-behind which only allows it to be enabled when other commands pass their validation checks). Instead of having to copy-paste this code-behind for each window I create which will have this, I would like to create this **ValidOKWindow**, which inherits **Window** and have all of my other windows inherit from it instead. However, I can't get this to work as-is.

I've tried creating **ValidOKWindow** as a child of **Window** and then substituting only the code-behind inheritance of its child classes:

```
public class WindowToInheritValidOK : ValidOKWindow
```

But the compiler hollers about the different base class in the .xaml (**<Window>**) which isn't suprising.

I've tried changing the base class in the .xaml as well

```
<ValidOKWindow x:Class="WPF.WindowToInheritValidOK"
```

But WPF apparently only allows its own classes as the base classes in the .xaml.

Since C# doesn't allow for multiple class inheritance, I don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any types outside of the basic framework itself which is included under the default xml namespace (`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`) you need to specify an xml namespace. For your own custom types in code this is usually done using an `xmlns` with `clr-namespace`. So if your `Window` classes are declared in a C# namespace "`WPF`" then that line should look like:

```
<local:ValidOKWindow x:Class="WPF.WindowToInheritValidOK" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
```

Comment: I'd tried doing that before but it didn't work, giving an error that XAML-built classes can't be used for other XAML classes. I thought that meant only standard classes could do it, but then I realized what it actually meant: I had to define ValidOKWindow as merely a .cs class, not as a Window (with XAML and .xaml.cs file). Doing that did the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah, there's inheritance of code but not XAML which seems like a bad limitation until you think about all the possible ambiguity that would come into play with inherited XAML.